# How to use fscanf in row, column to get a value

Tags: file, scanf

I am trying to read a .txt file that contains the value and its location (row and column) like this:

```
   0    0 1.00000000  1    1 1.00000000  2    2 1.00000000  0    3 2.00000000
```

My problem is that I don't know how to use the fscanf to read the file to separate row, column and value.

I have the text file and is not one set of number under the other but next to the other.